# PHP define() value confusion

Tags: php, function

```
define ("num", "12");
echo num%8;
```

From what I found from google, define() hold a constant value and the value is `num` and `12`. So my confusion is how come when `echo num%8` is equal to `4`? Can somebody explain this?

Comment: `12/8=1, 12%8=4` This is the [`modulo operation`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) which gives you the remainder after division.

Comment: i do understand that. But what this : define ("num", "12") really meant? is it num is holding a value of 12? so when echo num%8 is actually 12%8?

Comment: Why don't you [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)? On the page there are examples that show exactly this.

Comment: It really helps! Now I understand. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I've moved that to an answer.

Comment: this is what I got from the manual: define("CONSTANT", "Hello world.");
echo CONSTANT; // outputs "Hello world."     So in my question define ("num", "12") the output should be 12. That's why the answer is 4 when num%8. Thanks @MattClark !

Comment: Yes, _num_ is evaluated to `12`, but then the mathematical operation takes place. Anytime, happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The define function defines a variable *at runtime*, as the name suggests. So `define("num", "12")` just defines the variable named `num` with contents `"12"`.

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php):

> define — Defines a named constant

---

After that you have `num % 8` which essentially evaluates to `12 % 8`. At this point PHP converts your `String` value into an `Integer` value because you demand the `%` operator which operates on **numbers**. Therefore see `echo "12" % 8` which also outputs `4`.

As a small experiment, take a look at this:

```
define("num", "12");
echo gettype(num); // Outputs: string
echo gettype(num + 1); // Outputs: integer
```

So as you see PHP automatically converts the type if you demand it.

---

Last note that `%` is the **modulo operator**. It divides the number to the left by the number to the right and returns the **remainder**.
So `12 / 8` is `1` and a remainder of `4`. That is why it outputs `4`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I do understand now.